# POSIX positive lookup for sequence

Tags: regex, amazon-redshift

```
.*?(?=XYZ)
```

I currently have this regex which matches all characters up until a sequence denoted by (arbitrarily) 'XYZ' here. I'm executing it on Redshift in an attempt to strip a string of this sequence.

I get an unspecific error message when I run the query, and I used a POSIX regex parser to get more information. The following is the output of the parser

```
error parsing regexp: invalid or unsupported Perl syntax: `(?=`
```

Is there a way around this? It seems like from looking around positive lookup is not a thing with the Redshift syntax.

Comment: You can achieve the same with `(.*?)XYZ` and get Group 1 value.

Comment: Does Redshift support capturing groups? If so, you could do `^(.*?)XYZ` and use the results of the capture. (I'm not sure if [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/pattern-matching-conditions-posix.html) is the correct documentation, but if so, neither capturing groups nor the lazy quantifier `*?` appear to be supported.)

Comment: What about `split_part(col,'XYZ',1)`? If XYZ is a literal, this should suffice.

Comment: In this example XYZ occurs multiple times, I am trying to get the content after the Nth occurrence so the actual command is
`REGEXP_REPLACE( '(.*?(?=XYZ)XYZ){N-1}', '')`

Comment: Why is this tagged Perl when the error message specifically says it's not Perl?

Comment: @ChadPendergast Why do you need a positive lookahead then? Just use `(.*?XYZ){N-1}`.

Comment: :/ as mentioned by @ThisSuitIsBlackNot the lazy evaluator is also not supported.